# Can the PDB module of Biopython handle CONECT records

Tags: biopython

I'm investigating using biopython to process PDB files, but it looks to me like the CONECT records are not handled. For instance, I'm wanting to use it to extract a ligand from a PDB  structure, and I'm getting the atoms (HETATM) written but the corresponding CONECT records are lost. Is there a way to include these?

Comment: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/3468

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/3468:

Feature Request: Support for CONECT Records #3468
Open
zacharyrs opened this issue on 15 Jan · 4 comments
Open
Feature Request: Support for CONECT Records
#3468
zacharyrs opened this issue on 15 Jan · 4 comments
Comments
@zacharyrs
zacharyrs commented on 15 Jan

Hey all,

This isn't so much a feature request but a query to gauge interest.

I noticed in BioJava, there is built in support within the PDBParser for CONECT records (see here).
In contrast, BioPython lacks this, with the only related issue being here.

I'm just curious if there would be interest in me PR'ing with an implementation akin to BioJava, or if this is something I should just handle independently?

Cheers!
@JoaoRodrigues
Member
JoaoRodrigues commented on 15 Jan

Hi @zacharyrs

Thanks for opening the issue. CONECT records are a PDB-specific feature and have no correspondence to the newer (and now standard) mmCIF format. That said, I don't think there are any objections to adding them to the current parser, if you are so inclined! The CONECT record format parsed by Biojava is not standard either, by the way. There are no fields for the type of bond in the original format specification.
@zacharyrs
Author
zacharyrs commented on 17 Jan •

So I've read into the source for BioJava CONECT record handling, and also how it handles mmCIF with the bonds list. I'm thinking of implementing a connects instance attribute on the structure, and only reading/writing the CONECTs per the PDB spec (no bond type information).

The biggest hold up in this would be the copy methods - if you copy the structure you should retain the CONECTs, but for chain, residue, or atom I think you'd lose it, though I think this is similar to BioJava.
Old approach thoughts...

With a second day's thought and an implementation attempt, I've realised a few issues with the above (hidden) approaches.

My current approach (at zacharyrs:biopython/feature/conect_record_support) implements a Conect object, that takes two atom serial numbers, and the bond order.

When parsing, for each record I iterate through the bonded atoms and create individual Conect instances under the connects list attribute on the structure. For records that share a prior records atom serial numbers, I just increment the bond order. When writing, I construct a temporary dictionary, like shown, then just loop through and repeat records according to the order.

```
{
    atom_a_serial: {
        bond_order: [atom_b_serial]
    }
}
```

This works to read and then write a PDB, whilst preserving the CONECTS, however it does not behave if you modify the structure, as there's no link between the connects and the actual atoms. I could store the bond onto the actual atoms, akin to mmCIF under BioJava, but it might just be adding a lot of bloat for people who don't need the CONECT records...
@JoaoRodrigues
Member
JoaoRodrigues commented on 22 Mar

Hi @zacharyrs

Sorry for missing this follow-up. Implementing CONECT statements properly is hard because you'd need to keep track of who is connected to who. The simplest way is to add a dictionary of pairs of atom indexes but if you delete or add atoms, you risk mangling this info. Also, again, mmCIF files do not have an equivalent of CONECT statments.

You could, although I'm not sure how much I personally like that approach, just have a "bonds" attribute per atom that stores references to the atom objects it is bonded to. That way you wouldn't need to worry about indexes, but you'd have to have a way to cleanup these lists when you delete atoms otherwise you would have references left behind and the garbage cleaner wouldn't be happy about it.
@zacharyrs
Author
zacharyrs commented on 22 Mar

Hi @JoaoRodrigues - no worries, it's been a busy time for me too!

I ended up actually shifting to mmtf files, given they hold the bond information, so this has been dropped a little from my mind. I implemented a custom parser that retains all information and can serialise and deserialise easily, but that's a closed source project right now.

For the mmCIF/PDB approach, the bonds/conects attribute on the atom seems like the only feasible way to handle it. This is basically what I've done for mmtf files in my parser. I have a Bond instance that stores bond order and atom references, akin to the Conect instance described/implemented above. There's a helper on the Bond class that deletes it from both atoms, which I can then call as needed.